# Transparent background on CardView - Android

Tags: android, background, android-cardview

I want to do transparent background on CardView.
I know backgroundColor but i have image on my Layout.

Do you know how do it? Or something which work as cardview but i will set a transparent background?

Regards

Comment: DId you try `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: Should you use _cardBackgroundColor_ ?

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" dont work
I dont use backgroundColor because it has not option of transparent

Comment: I had the same problem, could NOT figure out how to make it transparent.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Setup your CardView to use the `cardBackgroundColor` attribute to remove color and `cardElevation` attribute to remove the drop shadow.  For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">
```

For a full list of supported attributes see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

If you are using an older API, you will need to call these two functions on your `CardView` instead:

```
myCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
myCardView.setCardElevation(0);
```

Comment: hi, it works, could you tell me the difference between android: and card_view: namespaces?

Comment: It is not working for api 19 but working for api 21. How too do it for lower APIs

Comment: @MuneebMirza call `setCardElevation()` and `setCardBackgroundColor()` from your code on you `CardView` See my edit.

Comment: ok i tried this answer and it worked :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810447/cardview-corner-background-not-transparent?rq=1

Comment: I tried to set `@null` but it didn't work, any idea?

Comment: I've had issue with setting black color with 20% opacity to card view, had line across view in center of it with different color. What solved this is to set elevation to 0dp and it disappeared.

Comment: it should be `myCardView.setCardElevation(0f);` because this method requires a float.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I need transparent bg but with shadow how to achieve that

Comment: To add to this, if you want a card border switch to `MaterialCardView` and define `strokeWidth` and `strokeColor`.

Answer (score 21):

**in SDK version 21 or higher steps to make Android `CardView` transparent.**

1. Set   `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`. This is `CardView` attribute to set background.
2. Set `android:cardElevation="0dp"` to remove the shadow.

*For example, here is small xml code to create transparent `CardView`*

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardElevation="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I used the **attribute**  `android:backgroundTint="@color/some_color"`,it is only used en **API level 21 and higher**. And `color #50000000` for example.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/negro_label"
        >
```

Answer (score 4):

use     `app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="16dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent" >

<--inside cardlayout-->

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work on **API 17**

```
cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add background color  app:cardBackgroundColor="#0000"

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#0000">
```

Answer (score 1):

What I wanted was to have a textview inside a cardview but I wanted the back of the cardview to be transparent. I solved it this way:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/semiTransparentColorr"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/cardview_stroke"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gold"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

First you need to set the value of the background color of the cardview to #1AFFFFFF (semiTransparentColorr). Then we give cardview_stroke.xml as background to linearlayout. cardview_stroke.xml codes should be like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/semiTransparentColorr"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black"></stroke>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have **cardView** to make image circle shape

```
       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#00424242"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/play_icon"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="#19000000"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).