# Trying to get transparent bg for Cardview

Tags: android

I have set both the CardView's background and FrameLayout's to transparent yet the result is still a white color bg.

Is this some default behavior? What should I change to my xml layout file for having a transparent bg ?

Layout file :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        tools:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayID"
            android:textColor="@color/link_text_material_light"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthID"
            android:textColor="@color/link_text_material_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splashID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/link_text_material_light"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            tools:text="Hero text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunbathMinsID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/link_text_material_light"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            tools:text="Hero text" />
    </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What have you defined in your theme? Is there a white background color?

Comment: I havent defines anything. It just extends AppCompat Light with ActionBar :    `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: I think white is the default window background color for this theme. Try to override this with "windowBackground" attribute. Set this to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

A transparent background can be obtained for any number of views within your XML.
This is a decent explanation for an imageview.
[Set transparent background of an imageview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-on-android)

Cardviews are a lot the same but have a little different attribute and are explained very well with the "app:cardBackgroundColor= "@android:color/transparent""
See this post for that type of attribute.
[Transparent background on CardView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629549/transparent-background-on-cardview-android)

Setting your cardView and the subsequent FrameLayout both to transparent will definitely get the job done and make both views transparent. However, the activity will always have a solid background. The Activity only doesn't have a solid background when you set a resource as the background and the views placed within that Activity will show the current background if they are set to transparent as seen in the links above.

Therefore, even though you have set your "views" to transparent, the Activity will always need a color or image to show the in background. Meaning that, yes you will still have a white background behind your cardView, unless you change that color.